# Ignoring comments in Nini

Tags: c#, nini

Is it possible to have ';' not delimiting comments only when it is on the right hand side of an equal side?

I have the following INI file:

> ; some comment that should be ignored
>
> [section]
>
> key=value1;value2;value2

With the following code, Nini is removing value2;value3 as it is regarded as a comment:

```csharp
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(iniFile))
            {
                IniDocument doc = new IniDocument(tr);
                foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in doc.Sections)
                {
                    string key = (string)entry.Key;
                    IniSection section = (IniSection)entry.Value;
                    if (section.Contains("key"))
                    {
                        // ... do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
```

Of course, I can do something like

```csharp
IniReader ir = new IniReader(tr);
ir.SetCommentDelimiters(new char[] { '!' });
IniDocument doc = new IniDocument(ir);
```

but then also the initial comment will be treated as a config file and result into an error ("expecting =").

Comment: Been awhile since I used Nini, but I think it will work if you put the value in quotes, that is `key="value1;value2;value3"`.  If you don't have control of the contents of the files then you might have to parse with something other than Nini.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the ini file and need to consume it as it is.

Comment: As said above, when e.g. setting it to '!' the first comment is treated as valid INI config and an error is thrown.

Comment: Do you have no control over the INI file then? You can't replace the delimiter for the comment or the value with another symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick scan of the code shows some useful properties you might be able to use:

```
result.AcceptCommentAfterKey = false;
result.SetCommentDelimiters (new char[] { ';', '#' });
```

Maybe setting that AcceptCommentAfterKey to false will help you? Otherwise, you could override the comment delimiter and replace the symbol you use for delimiting comments with whatever you want.